# How to order a list of paragraphs

Tags: c#, linq, list, sql-order-by

A have a list:
§ 21 Item
§ 1 Item
§ 13 Item
§ 3 Item
§ 2 Item

I need to order it like this:
§ 1 Item
§ 2 Item
§ 3 Item
§ 13 Item
§ 21 Item

But after

```
newList = (from a in list orderby a.Name ascending select a).ToList();
```

I get this:
§ 1 Item
§ 13 Item
§ 2 Item
§ 21 Item
§ 3 Item

How to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are looking for is a natural sort rather than the default lexical sort. A C# comparer that implements natural sort can be found at http://www.davekoelle.com/alphanum.html

Comment: Thanks. It works for me. I found also another class http://zootfroot.blogspot.com/2009/09/natural-sort-compare-with-linq-orderby.html

Answer (score 3):

```
... orderby int.Parse(a.Name.Split(" ")[1]) ...
```

Comment: I get exception if the a.Name is empty. Index was outside the bounds of the array. How to avoid it?

Answer (score 1):

to accomodate blank entry

```
newList = (from a in list 
           orderby String.IsNullOrEmpty(a) 
                     ? -1 
                     : int.Parse(a.Name.Split(" ")[1]) ascending 
           select a).ToList();
```

Comment: I assumed that empty item is on the top of the sorted list.

Answer (score 1):

Google has the answer: [Getting Linq to OrderBy an attribute value numerically](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/linqprojectgeneral/thread/7c4169c4-4c09-4aa2-9a31-17f0f8c985f7/).

```
from a in list
orderby int.Parse(a.Name)
select ...
```

Comment: a.Name can be empty or null. I get exception in this case: Input string was not in a correct format. How to solve it? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`01` is different from `1`. Lexicographically `13` comes before `3`. Presuming that all "paragraphs" are prepended with a non-zero-prefixed integer, you will need to parse each integer and order your list by that.

The previous answers will throw `FormatException` if a list item is not prefixed by an integer.

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
var list = new List<string> {"§ 21 Item", "§ 1 Item", "§ 13 Item", "§ 3 Item", "§ 2 Item"};
var orderedList = (from a in list orderby int.Parse(a.Split(' ')[1]) ascending select a).ToList();
```